# if loop dont jump to else

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i reach 5 the click event is still executable, but why it dont jump to else?

```
$(function () {
    let i = 0;
    if (i !== 5) {
        $(".grey").click(function () {
           // alert('Kasten ausgewaehlt');
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            i++;
            window.alert(i);//debugger
            return i;
        });
    } else {
        $(".grey").click(function () {
            alert('Kasten konnte nicht ausgewaehlt werden');

        })
    }


});
```

Comment: You are assigning a click-handler based on the value of `i`. You aren't handling the click based on the value of `i`. Move the `if/else` into the click function

Answer (score 2):

You initialize `i` to `0`, and *right after that* (when the page loads), you run the `if (i !== 5)` check - so, that `if` condition will always be fulfilled, and the `else` block will never be entered. Only the first listener (inside the `if`) is ever attached - the code for your second `.click` never runs.

Put the check inside the listener instead:

```
$(function () {
  let i = 0;
  $(".grey").click(function () {
    if (i !== 5) {
      // alert('Kasten ausgewaehlt');
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
      i++;
    } else {
      alert('Kasten konnte nicht ausgewaehlt werden');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` is not part of the click handler, so is only executed just after `i` is initialized to 0.